# Button triggers another view

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, button, view

Right now I have this:

```
 lazy var Button: UIButton = {
    let tb = UIButton()
    tb.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    tb.clipsToBounds = true
    tb.layer.cornerRadius = 39
    tb.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showButton), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    tb.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "buttonMenu"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    return tb
}()
```

How can I make the button take me to another view or do other stuff like opening the camera?

PS: The showButton function doesn't do anything really.

Comment: above code in viewcontroller 1 and you want access the button in another viewcontroller like a function access right ?

Answer (score 1):

So you have

```
tb.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showButton), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

but you need

```
tb.addTarget(self, action: #selector(className.showButton), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

func showButton(sender:UIButton) {
    //Code

}
```

Comment: and that class should have the elements of the new view and the constraints? or should I write it inside func showButton?

Comment: 'Let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 100))'.     'view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()'.               'Self.view.addSubview(view)'

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in 7.2.1 Xcode

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let Button: UIButton = {
        let tb = UIButton()
        tb.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)
        tb.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        tb.clipsToBounds = true
        tb.layer.cornerRadius = 39


        tb.addTarget(self, action: "showButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        // only change the action syntax like "action: "showButton:" "
        return tb
    }()

    self.view .addSubview(Button)

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func showButton(sender:AnyObject?) {
    //Code

}

}
```